# Как убрать из списка ','?

Tags: python, текст, re

`res = ['banana', ',' , 'apple']`

Kак мне убрать из `res` всё `','` ?

Comment: `list(filter(",".__ne__, res))`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов more readable: `list(filter(lambda elem: elem != ',', res))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно фильтром.

```
res = ['banana', ',' , 'apple']
temp = [row for row in res if ',' != row]

print(temp)
```

Comment: почему у всех `',' not in row` ? это ж ошибка

Comment: Потому что если in row, то скрипт выберет все элементы, которые совпадают с ','. Именно поэтому лямбда выражение является своеобразным фильтром в python. Т.е. элемент будет выбран, если row != ',' в моем случае.

Comment: `',' not in "123,7" == False`

Answer (score 6):

Как насчёт функционального программирования?

```
res = ['banana', ',' , 'apple']
new_res = list(filter(lambda a: a != ',', res))
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать так:

```
res = ['banana', ',' , 'apple']
res = [r for r in res if r != ',']
```

Или так например:

```
res = ['banana', ',', 'apple']
while ',' in res:
    res.remove(',')
```

Answer (score 2):

Мои 5 копеек

```py
import re

res = [re.sub(r',', '', elem) for elem in res]
# или
res = [elem.replace(',', '') for elem in res]

# если мы ко всему еще хотим избавиться от элементов в которых кроме запятых ничего нет тогда
res = [re.sub(r',', '', elem) for elem in res if re.sub(r',', '', elem)]
# или
res = [elem.replace(',', '') for elem in res if elem.replace(',', '')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Для примера с `ValueError`:

```
res = ['banana', ',' ,',', 'apple']
try:
    while True: res.remove(',')
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica там ',' in word делают. Авторы поправили что там было криво(вроде). Этот же ответ пример не лучше других, просто для разнообразия

Comment: ok.............